# Mobile First Encrypted Cache Errors

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using the IBM MobileFirst Studio Plugin 7.1 and am following the tutorial - Storing sensitive data in encrypted cache at this link:
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/data/storing-sensitive-data-encrypted-cache/

I have noticed that the ERROR CATALOG that I see is different than what is present in the documentation. This is a screen shot of my CATALOG

[image]

I am not able to see the ERRORS for the 
WL.EncryptedCache.ERROR_SECURE_RANDOM_GENERATOR_UNAVAILABLE
WL.EncryptedCache.ERROR_COULD_NOT_GENERATE_KEY

They are either mentioned in the code but not in the documentation or vice versa. Am I missing something? Please advise.

Comment: well, you unable to see . did you test it? is working or not as your expect?.

Comment: No it does not as the name space is not recognized
main.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ERROR_COULD_NOT_GENERATE_KEY' of undefined

Comment: I hope, @Idan Adar will be helping  you alternative way if you are  IBM costumer and should be handled as a PMR (support ticket). Once you open the PMR, please mention its number in the question or in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have dispatched a note to the development team to verify what is going on.
It appears we may have a defect here. Will update once news arrive.

Comment: Ok so just those errors are no longer in use. In that case the examples will also need some sprucing up